# How to write both async and blocking method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I use both blocking and asynchronous method in my program. 
My blocking method use asynchronous method with .GetAwaiter().GetResult(). But in different sources said that better to create separate Blocking and Async methods
How to correctly write the code if I need BOTH blocking and asynchronous calls? Create two methods?

For example - use async methods in WPF and blocking in thread/timer/background worker

Comment: Yes, just like microsoft does in it's framework, create separate methods. And don't ever use `GetResult` or `Result`. That's just not good. Only if you feel THERE IS ABSOLUTELY NO OTHER WAY, try using JoinableTaskFactory.

Comment: for starters there is very little need to ever use this `.GetAwaiter().GetResult().` if you are there is a good chance there is something that needs to be redesigned. Also async and await is blocking.. in all honesty, you should probably just make your code async, if thats not possible, make 2 version of the method (at last resort), and never mix them both with things list Result or GetResult ect

Comment: @TheGeneral No, `await` is *not* blocking.  Literally the whole point of it existing is to allow you to write non-blocking code more effectively.

Comment: @Servy i agree, and i am quite aware of what `await` does and the *continuation* that gets executed. The term *block* was relative to the code that gets executed sequentially and the continuation. anyway i think the point may have been lost a little by the looks of it

Comment: @TheGeneral Performing operations sequentially and blocking are *radically* different things, and the terms cannot be used interchangeably.  If you want to say that the statements will be executed sequentially, then say that.

Comment: I think you are grinding you axe you axe for the wrong reasons, and once again you have missed the point, however since you have clarified and left no ambiguity i cant complain

Comment: Trying to understand you OP... do you need too call a synchronous and a asynchronous method from inside a method?? do you have a **small** code snippet?

Comment: @siggi_pop I want to know what to do if theoretically I need to call one method blocking and async from different places

Comment: Ok i understand, let's name a method A, and so sometimes you need to call method A from method B and A should run synchronous. But sometimes you need to call method A from method C and then A should run asynchronous. Is that correct??

Comment: @siggi_pop Yes!

Comment: @siggi_pop For example async method in WPF and blocking in thread / background worker / timer

Answer (score -1):

**Edit** As other have mentioned, it is bad practice to have a method that acts as async and sync. Moderator has cleaned up my initial answer which did contain other bad practices like `async void` which is reserved for event methods. So basically, don't do it this way! Find a better way.

Here is a example of how that's done. 
the method `PrintToConsole` can run Async or Sync (default sync), you just have to pass some information to tell which route to take. Here i have used an enum as example.

```
public enum runAsync {
    No = 0,
    Yes =1
}

public static async Task PrintToConsole(string inVal, runAsync method = runAsync.No)
{
    if (method == runAsync.Yes)
    {
        await Task.Dealy();                
        Console.WriteLine(inVal + "async");
    }            
    else
    {
         Console.WriteLine(inVal + "sync");
    }
}

static async Task Main(string[] args) {

    Console.WriteLine("Async: Started");
    await PrintToConsole("Async: Finished!", runAsync.Yes);
    Console.WriteLine("Sync: Started");
    PrintToConsole("Sync: Finished!");
    Console.ReadLine();


    return;
}
```

And the result is:

```bsh
"Async: Started"
"Sync: Started"
"Sync: Finished!"
"Async: Finished!"
```

In real code you'd use alternative APIs in each branch like `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` and `ExecuteNonQuery` correspondingly.

Comment: For me it was the use of `async void` which is a huge no.

Comment: @Jamiec You prefer it was `async Task` / `async Task<T>` rigth?

Comment: I've updated sample slightly to be less questionable (return `Task`, properly `await` async version and use true async `Task.Delay` rather than bad practice example of wrapping synchronous Sleep into task)… While post actually answers question as asked the whole idea of having same method to implement two completely different behaviors is strange... some other approach to overall architecture would be better (i.e. inject on of  two implementations as dependency, or go 100% async,...)